# Elasticsearch .tasks index usage

Tags: elasticsearch

The reindex operation in Elasticsearch creates an entry in ".tasks" index.

Following is the excerpt from [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#_url_parameters_3):

> If the request contains wait_for_completion=false then Elasticsearch will perform some preflight checks, launch the request, and then return a task which can be used with Tasks APIs to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch **will also create a record of this task as a document** at .tasks/task/${taskId}. This is yours to keep or remove as you see fit. When you are done with it, delete it so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space it uses

However, If i disable creating index dynamically by using [this API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation)/property, **then .tasks index is not created** during reindex and the operation gets successful.

My question is,

- Will this affect the normal processing of Elastic (specially the reindex operation) ?
- Was this ".tasks" index exists in versions before 6.6 ?

Comment: What version did you do it with?  I set `"action.auto_create_index": "false"` and .tasks was still created on v6.6.2.

Comment: I tried on 6.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.tasks` index exists at least since ES 5.0 and the purpose is to let you manage your long-running tasks instead of letting them run and finish without seeing their outcome.

The normal processing is in no way affected by this, that index is just a container for tasks outcome that you can consult at your leisure. However, if you decide to store tasks outcome in there, it's your job to keep that index clean, i.e. ES will not delete task documents from that index.